# Unable to fix 404 NOT FOUND error because I cannot see and access the files in ec2 created by Elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am a bit new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk
I used AWS Elastic Beanstalk to create a PHP 7 deployment for a Laravel project which runs perfectly on my laptop. then uploaded my Laravel project files, edited the .env file
Now I'm getting a 404 Not Found error
[image: 404 webpage]
On the elastic beanstalk console, the health of the server is ok but I am still getting the 404 not found error. Please help me fix this
[image: public path already set]
Can I create an IAM user or pen file that will allow me to access the ec2 via ssh?
[image: the health of server is ok]
How do I fix the 404 NOT FOUND error because I cannot see and access the files in ec2 created by  Elastic beanstalk
[image: unable to launch terminal in ec2 console]
see logs from the server below

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2021/05/02 10:37:13 [error] 3601#0: *1 "/var/www/html/public/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 203.159.80.30, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "18.222.4.168:80"
2021/05/02 10:37:13 [error] 3601#0: *1 testing "/var/www/html/public" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: 203.159.80.30, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "18.222.4.168:80"
2021/05/02 10:43:42 [error] 3601#0: *2 "/var/www/html/public/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 129.205.124.143, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "trikleqtspendapi-env.eba-ghdkmh8i.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2021/05/02 10:43:42 [error] 3601#0: *2 testing "/var/www/html/public" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: 129.205.124.143, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "trikleqtspendapi-env.eba-ghdkmh8i.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
2021/05/02 10:31:29.364543 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start aws-eb.target
2021/05/02 10:31:29.368812 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable healthd.service
2021/05/02 10:31:29.449379 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2021/05/02 10:31:29.454445 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active healthd.service
2021/05/02 10:31:29.457846 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start healthd.service
2021/05/02 10:31:29.482778 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_logformat.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/healthd_logformat.conf
2021/05/02 10:31:29.484360 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_nginx.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf
2021/05/02 10:31:29.486171 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure php-fpm
2021/05/02 10:31:29.491762 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure log streaming
2021/05/02 10:31:29.491773 [INFO] log streaming is not enabled
2021/05/02 10:31:29.491776 [INFO] disable log stream
2021/05/02 10:31:29.491789 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
2021/05/02 10:31:29.501425 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
2021/05/02 10:31:29.507101 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetToggleForceRotate
2021/05/02 10:31:29.507113 [INFO] Checking if logs need forced rotation
2021/05/02 10:31:29.507131 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:630589988206:stack/awseb-e-pw9i7apndy-stack/5104d330-ab31-11eb-815f-0a30b5a1ab58 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-2
2021/05/02 10:31:30.087814 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:630589988206:stack/awseb-e-pw9i7apndy-stack/5104d330-ab31-11eb-815f-0a30b5a1ab58 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-2
2021/05/02 10:31:30.620774 [INFO] Procfile not found. Generating default rsyslog config
2021/05/02 10:31:30.621989 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl restart rsyslog.service
2021/05/02 10:31:30.639310 [INFO] Executing instruction: PostBuildEbExtension
2021/05/02 10:31:30.639330 [INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.
2021/05/02 10:31:30.639343 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:630589988206:stack/awseb-e-pw9i7apndy-stack/5104d330-ab31-11eb-815f-0a30b5a1ab58 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-2 --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2021/05/02 10:31:30.957729 [INFO] Finished executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.

2021/05/02 10:31:30.957750 [INFO] Executing instruction: CleanEbExtensions
2021/05/02 10:31:30.957774 [INFO] Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from app staging directory.
2021/05/02 10:31:30.957778 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreDeployHooks
2021/05/02 10:31:30.957798 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/predeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/05/02 10:31:30.957803 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop X-Ray
2021/05/02 10:31:30.957807 [INFO] stop X-Ray ...
2021/05/02 10:31:30.957821 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf xray.service
2021/05/02 10:31:30.965110 [WARN] stopProcess Warning: process xray is not registered 
2021/05/02 10:31:30.965139 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop xray.service
2021/05/02 10:31:30.972353 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop proxy
2021/05/02 10:31:30.972370 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf httpd.service
2021/05/02 10:31:30.980459 [WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process httpd is not registered, skipping...

2021/05/02 10:31:30.980487 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/05/02 10:31:30.986489 [WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process nginx is not registered, skipping...

2021/05/02 10:31:30.986501 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop php-fpm
2021/05/02 10:31:30.986522 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf php-fpm.service
2021/05/02 10:31:30.991331 [WARN] stopProcess Warning: process php-fpm is not registered 
2021/05/02 10:31:30.991360 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop php-fpm.service
2021/05/02 10:31:30.995942 [INFO] Executing instruction: FlipApplication
2021/05/02 10:31:30.996531 [INFO] create soft link from /var/app/current/ to /var/www/html
2021/05/02 10:31:30.996560 [INFO] Executing instruction: start X-Ray
2021/05/02 10:31:30.996567 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2021/05/02 10:31:30.996572 [INFO] Executing instruction: start php-fpm
2021/05/02 10:31:30.996641 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf php-fpm.service
2021/05/02 10:31:31.002929 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/05/02 10:31:31.073037 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/05/02 10:31:31.076919 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf php-fpm.service
2021/05/02 10:31:31.081715 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active php-fpm.service
2021/05/02 10:31:31.085118 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start php-fpm.service
2021/05/02 10:31:31.349359 [INFO] Executing instruction: start proxy with new configuration
2021/05/02 10:31:31.349393 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
2021/05/02 10:31:31.370795 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/proxy/staging/nginx/* /etc/nginx
2021/05/02 10:31:31.374022 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/05/02 10:31:31.380855 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/05/02 10:31:31.457630 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/05/02 10:31:31.461627 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/05/02 10:31:31.466574 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active nginx.service
2021/05/02 10:31:31.469974 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start nginx.service
2021/05/02 10:31:31.505744 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2021/05/02 10:31:31.505760 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip configure sqsd daemon ...
2021/05/02 10:31:31.505765 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2021/05/02 10:31:31.505769 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip start sqsd daemon ...
2021/05/02 10:31:31.505777 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
2021/05/02 10:31:31.505782 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
2021/05/02 10:31:31.505794 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
2021/05/02 10:31:31.512459 [INFO] php-fpm.service nginx.service healthd.service cfn-hup.service

2021/05/02 10:31:31.512478 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2021/05/02 10:31:31.517149 [INFO] 

2021/05/02 10:31:31.517270 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2021/05/02 10:31:31.517283 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/05/02 10:31:31.517287 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/05/02 10:31:31.517408 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: You didn't include a 'composer.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install Composer dependencies.","timestamp":1619951489,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1619951491,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}

2021/05/02 10:31:31.517585 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2021/05/02 10:47:20.878327 [INFO] Starting...
2021/05/02 10:47:20.878386 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2021/05/02 10:47:20.878402 [INFO] reading event message file
2021/05/02 10:47:20.878500 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2021/05/02 10:47:20.878563 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2021/05/02 10:47:20.957130 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:630589988206:stack/awseb-e-pw9i7apndy-stack/5104d330-ab31-11eb-815f-0a30b5a1ab58 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-2
2021/05/02 10:47:21.259415 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:630589988206:stack/awseb-e-pw9i7apndy-stack/5104d330-ab31-11eb-815f-0a30b5a1ab58 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-2
2021/05/02 10:47:21.609138 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2021/05/02 10:47:21.609153 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, this instance should execute the command
2021/05/02 10:47:21.609157 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2021/05/02 10:47:21.609207 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2021/05/02 10:47:21.609212 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2021/05/02 10:47:21.609472 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/access.log
2021/05/02 10:47:21.611205 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2021/05/02 10:47:21.612684 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log
```

Comment: i feel really sad because nobody in the world is able to help me fix this issue :(

Comment: The easiest way to get direct access to an Elastic Beanstalk instance is via the [EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html). After you have installed the CLI and configured it properly you can use commands like: `eb list`, `eb use`, `eb ssh` to view, configure, and access your EB Apps and Instances. You can also find instructions to SSH directly in the 3rd tab of the screenshot you included. Lastly, EB doesn't leverage an `.env` file. Environment variables are defined in the Configuration > Software > Environment properties section of EB Admin online.

Answer (score 0):

I retested the uploaded folder on a different server and noticed there was an issue with the folder structure and fixed it and it's fine now
Thanks for your imput

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a t2.* instance helped solve this issue for me. I think AWS needs to look into arm based instances, since they're the ones with the issue.